# Converting 0-9 to n in query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've found several examples on SO that employ a UDF, but I'm trying to do this without a UDF.

I'm querying a table, grabbing the most recent @topCount number of records, converting digits 0 to 9 into lowercase n, and displaying the unique values.

It works, but I was hoping to get some input on a better way, if one exists.

If a UDF is the answer, then I'll go fight that fight.

```
DECLARE @topCount AS INT;
DECLARE @fromCharacter AS CHAR(1);
DECLARE @toCharacter AS CHAR(1);

SET @topCount = 2000;
SET @toCharacter = 'n';

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_tbl') IS NOT NULL   DROP TABLE #temp_tbl;

SELECT TOP(@topCount)
    LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(msg_text AS VARCHAR(MAX)))) AS msgText     --msg_text is a datatype text
    , msg_srce_text
    , creat_gdat
INTO #temp_tbl
FROM dbo.appl_log
ORDER BY
    id DESC                                                     --id is the PK
;

SET @fromCharacter = '0';
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msgText = REPLACE(msgText, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msgText) > 0;
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msg_srce_text = REPLACE(msg_srce_text, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msg_srce_text) > 0;

SET @fromCharacter = '1';
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msgText = REPLACE(msgText, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msgText) > 0;
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msg_srce_text = REPLACE(msg_srce_text, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msg_srce_text) > 0;

SET @fromCharacter = '2';
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msgText = REPLACE(msgText, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msgText) > 0;
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msg_srce_text = REPLACE(msg_srce_text, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msg_srce_text) > 0;

SET @fromCharacter = '3';
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msgText = REPLACE(msgText, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msgText) > 0;
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msg_srce_text = REPLACE(msg_srce_text, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msg_srce_text) > 0;

SET @fromCharacter = '4';
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msgText = REPLACE(msgText, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msgText) > 0;
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msg_srce_text = REPLACE(msg_srce_text, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msg_srce_text) > 0;

SET @fromCharacter = '5';
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msgText = REPLACE(msgText, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msgText) > 0;
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msg_srce_text = REPLACE(msg_srce_text, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msg_srce_text) > 0;

SET @fromCharacter = '6';
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msgText = REPLACE(msgText, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msgText) > 0;
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msg_srce_text = REPLACE(msg_srce_text, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msg_srce_text) > 0;

SET @fromCharacter = '7';
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msgText = REPLACE(msgText, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msgText) > 0;
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msg_srce_text = REPLACE(msg_srce_text, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msg_srce_text) > 0;

SET @fromCharacter = '8';
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msgText = REPLACE(msgText, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msgText) > 0;
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msg_srce_text = REPLACE(msg_srce_text, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msg_srce_text) > 0;

SET @fromCharacter = '9';
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msgText = REPLACE(msgText, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msgText) > 0;
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET
    msg_srce_text = REPLACE(msg_srce_text, @fromCharacter, @toCharacter)
WHERE CHARINDEX(@fromCharacter, msg_srce_text) > 0;

SELECT MIN(creat_gdat) AS fromDateTime, MAX(creat_gdat) AS toDateTime, @topCount AS mostRecent FROM #temp_tbl;

SELECT
    msgText
    , msg_srce_text
    , COUNT(*) AS count
    , MAX(creat_gdat) AS mostRecentDateTime
FROM #temp_tbl
GROUP BY
    msgText
    , msg_srce_text
ORDER BY
    msgText DESC
;

GO
```

Comment: msgText has a wide range of data. Sometimes it's an XML message. Other times it's a message in a sentence structure, so A-Z, space, and punctuation. Pretty much anything ASCII from space to tilde, and possible some extended ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Using `REPLACE FUNCTION` u can replace all the numeric data.Try this..

```
UPDATE #temp_tbl
SET    msgtext = Replace (Replace (Replace (Replace (Replace (Replace (
                 Replace (Replace (Replace (Replace (
                 msgtext, '0', 'n'), '1', 'n'), '2', 'n'), '3', 'n'), '4', 'n'), 
                 '5', 'n'), '6', 'n'), '7', 'n'), '8', 'n'), '9', 'n'),
       msg_srce_text = Replace (Replace (Replace (Replace (Replace (Replace 
                      (Replace (Replace (Replace (Replace 
                      (msg_srce_text,'0', 'n'), '1', 'n'), '2', 'n'), '3', 'n'), '4', 'n'), 
                 '5', 'n'), '6', 'n'), '7', 'n'), '8', 'n'), '9', 'n')
```